# Proof of the Catalan number formula using Dyck walks

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, catalan-numbers

In our notes we were given the formula $$C(n)=\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$$

It was proved by counting the number of paths above the line $y=0$ from $(0,0)$ to $(2n,0)$ using $n(1,1)$ up arrows and $n(1,-1)$ down arrows.

The notes are a bit unclear and I'm wondering if somebody could clarify for me. There is talk of reflections over the line $y=-1$ and how there are $\binom{2n}{n+1}$ paths from $(0,-2)$ to $(2n,0)$, but I can't see why this is. There is a similar proof on wikipedia but I'm more interested in this specific method.

Comment: I think the reason nobody responded to this question is that it is not clear what exactly you need. The method you learned is likely the same as the method used on Wikipedia, just rotated by $45^\circ$ ...